# "Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain" After running tsc command in typescript , after updating backend

Tags: typescript, vue.js, openssl

After adding new features to my backend code and updating the dist folder using TypeScript Compiler (tsc), I encountered an error stating "Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain." It seems that the issue arises when OpenSSL is enabled. Disabling OpenSSL resolves the problem, but I'm keen on ensuring that the server works seamlessly with OpenSSL enabled.

Could someone provide guidance on how to resolve this issue while keeping OpenSSL enabled? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: A self-signed certificate cannot be trusted unless you are confident you know where it's from. The issue comes up when doing testing on a local deployment, because it's a pain to get a real certificate (well less now than in the past). Where this certificate came from in your case is impossible to say without more information.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. Well, everything was working fine, but after running "tsc," I started to get this error. Should I generate a new certificate? Also, what exact information do you need? I will be more than happy to provide that information